# Errors running xcode 3.2.2 on Lion

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, testing

Just installed xcode 3.2.2 (on Lion) so I can test my app for the iOS 3.0 and 3.2
Created a simple test app based on View application template.
Just trying to build it gives me the following error.

[image]

Comment: Try the latest version of Xcode 3, which is 3.2.6.

Comment: @Cyprian: i have same problem ... please let me know if your problem solved. I want to develop an application for my old iphone 2G. with (jailbreaked) ios version 3.1.3. my email : kogan.michel [at] gmail dot com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt you can use XCode 3 with Lion, even I was using XCode 4 and had to update to 4.1 to run on Lion.

However if using XCode 3 is mandatory for you I found [some post](http://anatomicwax.tumblr.com/post/8064949186/installing-xcode-3-2-6-on-lion-redux) explaining how to do so but it seemed tricky. In his [original post](http://anatomicwax.tumblr.com/post/7906770311/installing-xcode-3-2-6-on-lion) he clearly mentions the same problem as you're having.

Answer (score 1):

You can (must? should?) use the latest version Xcode and still target the older iOS. I see that you're trying to do this presumably to use the simulator, but I'd strongly recommend testing on the actual devices with the older versions of iOS.